# Mathematica VectorPlot with Piecewise arguments

Tags: mathematica

Why won't this output the VectorPlot? It outputs number (that even seems correct for the application), but I can't get a picture out of them :(

```
BbuitenBolR[r_, \[Theta]_, R_] := Cos[\[Theta]] (1 - R (3 + R^2 - 3 R Coth[R])/r^3) /. R -> 1
BbuitenBolT[r_, \[Theta]_, R_] := -Sin[\[Theta]] (1 + R (3 + R^2 - 3 R Coth[R])/r^3) /. R -> 1
BbinnenBolR[r_, \[Theta]_, R_] := Cos[\[Theta]] (3 R)/Sinh[R] (r Cosh[r] - Sinh[r])/r^3 /. R -> 1
BbinnenBolT[r_, \[Theta]_, R_] := -Sin[\[Theta]] (3 R)/( 2 Sinh[R]) ((1 + r^2) Sinh[r] - r Cosh[r])/r^3 /. R -> 1
Br[r_, \[Theta]_, R_] := Piecewise[{{BbinnenBolR[r, \[Theta], R], r <= R}, {BbuitenBolR[r, \[Theta], R], r > R}}];
Bt[r_, \[Theta]_, R_] := Piecewise[{{BbinnenBolT[r, \[Theta], R], r <= R}, {BbuitenBolT[r, \[Theta], R], r > R}}];
Bx[x_, z_, R_] := x/ArcCos[z/Sqrt[x^2 + z^2]] Br[ArcCos[z/Sqrt[x^2 + z^2]], ArcCos[z/Sqrt[x^2 + z^2]], R] + z/ArcCos[z/Sqrt[x^2 + z^2]] Bt[ArcCos[z/Sqrt[x^2 + z^2]],  ArcCos[z/Sqrt[x^2 + z^2]], R]
Bz[x_, z_, R_] := z/ArcCos[z/Sqrt[x^2 + z^2]] Br[ArcCos[z/Sqrt[x^2 + z^2]], ArcCos[z/Sqrt[x^2 + z^2]], R] - x/ArcCos[z/Sqrt[x^2 + z^2]] Bt[ArcCos[z/Sqrt[x^2 + z^2]], ArcCos[z/Sqrt[x^2 + z^2]], R]
Manipulate[N[Bx[1, 1, R]], {R, 1, 10}]
Bz[1, 1, 1] // N

Manipulate[ VectorPlot[{N[Bx[x, z, R]], N[Bz[x, z, R]]}, {x, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}], {R, 1, 10}]
```

I'm sorry for the messy code, but Mathematica copy-pastes that way. I checked out the Piecewise examples and the VectorPlot examples, but no luck on combining the two :( Is there an alternative way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `/. R -> 1` seems strange to me.  What do you mean to accomplish with that?

Nevertheless, adding `Hold` gives output of some kind:

```
Manipulate[VectorPlot[Hold@{N[Bx[x, z, R]], N[Bz[x, z, R]]}, {x, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}], {R, 1, 10}]
```

Comment: Yeah, that should be removed. I changed the function to use `HeavisideTheta` instead of Piecewise, and now it works as it should. Don't really know where I went wrong...

Comment: @rubenvb, would you consider posting your new code, if not in this question, then perhaps to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?  Also, I don't think this answer deserves the check mark; it has no explanation, and was a quick fix (if it even gives the right output) I stumbled upon before I had to leave.  I can take another look at this in about six hours.